# Cannot get files when lazy loading a module

Tags: angular, typescript, lazy-loading

I'm trying to lazy load some modules on my angular 2 application but when I go to the route for a particular module the GET request seems to be messed up.

app-routing.module.ts

```js
const routes = [
  {path: 'products', loadChildren: './products/products.module#ProductsModule'},
  {path: 'user', loadChildren: './user/user.module#UserModule'},
  {path: '**', redirectTo: '/products'}
]
```

product-routing.module.ts

```js
const routes: Routes = [
  {path: '', component: ProductsComponent}
];
```

user-routing.module.ts

```js
const routes: Routes = [
  {path: 'login', component: LoginComponent},
  {path: 'register', component: RegisterComponent},
  {path: 'reset-password', component: ResetPasswordComponent},
  {path: 'profile', component: ProfileComponent}
];
```

The product route works perfectly but the user routes don't seem to work which I believe is due to the following console error:

`GET http://localhost:4200/user/inline.bundle.js net::ERR_ABORTED`

For some reason user is being added into the url to get all of my assets. I'm guessing I've done something wrong with the routing but I'm not entirely sure what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have `''` empty path in user module? You should create some redirect empty pass for your user module because your path is at `/user/` when UserModule was lazy loaded and there isn't a route to it.

user-routing.module.ts

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {path: '', redirectTo: 'login', pathMatch: 'full'},
  {path: 'login', component: LoginComponent},
  {path: 'register', component: RegisterComponent},
  {path: 'reset-password', component: ResetPasswordComponent},
  {path: 'profile', component: ProfileComponent}
];
```